# Cannot access admin dashboard after Laravel backpack/pro installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I've tried to create three new laravel projects but i still got same error after login:

> TypeError
> Argument 2 passed to Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel::getViewNamespacesFromConfigFor() must be an instance of Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\Traits\mixed or null, string given, called in C:\xxx\vendor\backpack\crud\src\app\Library\CrudPanel\Traits\HasViewNamespaces.php on line 71 (View: C:\xxx\vendor\backpack\crud\src\resources\views\base\inc\widgets.blade.php)

I can access admin dashboard without backpack/pro.
My licence for backpack/pro is valid till next year.

Answer (score 0):

There was [a bug in the 5.2.0 release](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/4531).

It's been fixed in 5.2.1, so a `composer update backpack/crud` should fix it for you.